# How do I display the social button where I want?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I don't want it to display in the_content. With the_content, it adds a p tag, and i don't want that. I want it display in woocommerce_share hook. How do I do that?
when I try add_action or add_filter code , it doesn't work. I just want to display it in woocommerce product page and my custom post type "Journals"
My custom post type is a blog post. When the user click the post, in the post I want the social icons to show up.

```
add_filter( 'IS_THERE_A_CUSTOM_FILTER_I_CAN_USE_WITHOUT_THE_P_TAG', 'crunchify_social_sharing_buttons');

add_action( 'woocommerce_share', 'crunchify_social_sharing_buttons');
```

functions.php

```
function crunchify_social_sharing_buttons($content) {
    if(is_singular() || is_home()){

        // Get current page URL 
        $crunchifyURL = get_permalink();

        // Get current page title
        $crunchifyTitle = str_replace( ' ', '%20', get_the_title());

        // Get Post Thumbnail for pinterest
        $crunchifyThumbnail = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( $post->ID ), 'full' );

        // Construct sharing URL without using any script
        $twitterURL = 'https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text='.$crunchifyTitle.'&amp;url='.$crunchifyURL.'&amp;via=Crunchify';
        $facebookURL = 'https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u='.$crunchifyURL;
        $googleURL = 'https://plus.google.com/share?url='.$crunchifyURL;
        $bufferURL = 'https://bufferapp.com/add?url='.$crunchifyURL.'&amp;text='.$crunchifyTitle;

        // Based on popular demand added Pinterest too
        $pinterestURL = 'https://pinterest.com/pin/create/button/?url='.$crunchifyURL.'&amp;media='.$crunchifyThumbnail[0].'&amp;description='.$crunchifyTitle;

        // Add sharing button at the end of page/page content
        $content .= '<div class="crunchify-social">';
        $content .= '<h5>SHARE ON</h5> <a class="crunchify-link crunchify-twitter" href="'. $twitterURL .'" target="_blank">Twitter</a>';
        $content .= '<a class="crunchify-link crunchify-facebook" href="'.$facebookURL.'" target="_blank">Facebook</a>';
        $content .= '<a class="crunchify-link crunchify-googleplus" href="'.$googleURL.'" target="_blank">Google+</a>';
        $content .= '<a class="crunchify-link crunchify-buffer" href="'.$bufferURL.'" target="_blank">Buffer</a>';
        $content .= '<a class="crunchify-link crunchify-pinterest" href="'.$pinterestURL.'" target="_blank">Pin It</a>';
        $content .= '</div>';

        return $content;
    }else{
        // if not a post/page then don't include sharing button
        return $content;
    }
};
add_filter( 'the_content', 'crunchify_social_sharing_buttons');
```

style.css

```
.crunchify-link {
    padding: 4px 8px 6px 8px;
    color: white;
    font-size: 12px;
    border-radius: 2px;
    margin-right: 2px;
    cursor: pointer;
    -moz-background-clip: padding;
    -webkit-background-clip: padding-box;
    box-shadow: inset 0 -3px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.2);
    -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 -3px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.2);
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 -3px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.2);
}

.crunchify-link:hover,.crunchify-link:active {
    color: white;
}

.crunchify-twitter {
    background: #00aced;
}

.crunchify-twitter:hover,.crunchify-twitter:active {
    background: #0084b4;
}

.crunchify-facebook {
    background: #3B5997;
}

.crunchify-facebook:hover,.crunchify-facebook:active {
    background: #2d4372;
}

.crunchify-googleplus {
    background: #D64937;
}

.crunchify-googleplus:hover,.crunchify-googleplus:active {
    background: #b53525;
}

.crunchify-buffer {
    background: #444;
}

.crunchify-buffer:hover,.crunchify-buffer:active {
    background: #222;
}

.crunchify-pinterest {
    background: #bd081c;
}

.crunchify-pinterest:hover,.crunchify-pinterest:active {
    background: #bd081c;
}
.crunchify-social {
    margin: 20px 0px 25px 0px;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    font-size: 12px;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> add_filter( 'IS_THERE_A_CUSTOM_FILTER_I_CAN_USE_WITHOUT_THE_P_TAG', 'crunchify_social_sharing_buttons');

No, there is not. Anything that is added via the `the_content` filter is ultimately displayed as:

```
apply_filters( 'the_content', $content );
```

And the filters that are applied include `wpautop()`. Your `crunchify_social_sharing_buttons` function that is filtering the content filter is *returning* a value. To display the buttons from your custom function on the `woocommerce_share` hook you would need to *echo* the value.

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_share', 'crunchify_social_sharing_buttons');
function crunchify_social_sharing_buttons($content) {
    if(is_singular() || is_home()){

        // Get current page URL 
        $crunchifyURL = get_permalink();

        // Get current page title
        $crunchifyTitle = str_replace( ' ', '%20', get_the_title());

        // Get Post Thumbnail for pinterest
        $crunchifyThumbnail = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( $post->ID ), 'full' );

        // Construct sharing URL without using any script
        $twitterURL = 'https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text='.$crunchifyTitle.'&amp;url='.$crunchifyURL.'&amp;via=Crunchify';
        $facebookURL = 'https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u='.$crunchifyURL;
        $googleURL = 'https://plus.google.com/share?url='.$crunchifyURL;
        $bufferURL = 'https://bufferapp.com/add?url='.$crunchifyURL.'&amp;text='.$crunchifyTitle;

        // Based on popular demand added Pinterest too
        $pinterestURL = 'https://pinterest.com/pin/create/button/?url='.$crunchifyURL.'&amp;media='.$crunchifyThumbnail[0].'&amp;description='.$crunchifyTitle;

        // Add sharing button at the end of page/page content
        $content .= '<div class="crunchify-social">';
        $content .= '<h5>SHARE ON</h5> <a class="crunchify-link crunchify-twitter" href="'. $twitterURL .'" target="_blank">Twitter</a>';
        $content .= '<a class="crunchify-link crunchify-facebook" href="'.$facebookURL.'" target="_blank">Facebook</a>';
        $content .= '<a class="crunchify-link crunchify-googleplus" href="'.$googleURL.'" target="_blank">Google+</a>';
        $content .= '<a class="crunchify-link crunchify-buffer" href="'.$bufferURL.'" target="_blank">Buffer</a>';
        $content .= '<a class="crunchify-link crunchify-pinterest" href="'.$pinterestURL.'" target="_blank">Pin It</a>';
        $content .= '</div>';

        echo $content;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you . it works. One last question, when I click facebook or pinterest, I don't see the image I am sharing . Is that normal if I don't see the image because I am using localhost now? If I put on the server will i see the image? Also I solve the problem with add_filter yesterday. Check my answer below if that is correct too.

Comment: Your answer below is messy. Just echo the value and add the action once as I've shown. Not sure exactly what you mean about the image, but I assume you don't have open graph tags, which is a totally separate question.

Answer (score 0):

This works, but for my social-bar.php code I remove the $value in add_filter. I'm not sure if that is the right way to do it. Because I don't to print any value. Can someone correct me if this is the right way to do it. Thanks

```
 echo apply_filters( 'social_bar');
```

FUNCTION.php

function crunchify_social_sharing_buttons($content) {
        if(is_singular() || is_home()){

```
        // Get current page URL 
        $crunchifyURL = get_permalink();

        // Get current page title
        $crunchifyTitle = str_replace( ' ', '%20', get_the_title());

        // Get Post Thumbnail for pinterest
        $crunchifyThumbnail = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( $post->ID ), 'full' );

        // Construct sharing URL without using any script
        $twitterURL = 'https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text='.$crunchifyTitle.'&amp;url='.$crunchifyURL.'&amp;via=Crunchify';
        $facebookURL = 'https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u='.$crunchifyURL;
        $googleURL = 'https://plus.google.com/share?url='.$crunchifyURL;
        $bufferURL = 'https://bufferapp.com/add?url='.$crunchifyURL.'&amp;text='.$crunchifyTitle;

        // Based on popular demand added Pinterest too
        $pinterestURL = 'https://pinterest.com/pin/create/button/?url='.$crunchifyURL.'&amp;media='.$crunchifyThumbnail[0].'&amp;description='.$crunchifyTitle;

        // Add sharing button at the end of page/page content
        $content .= '<div class="crunchify-social">';
        $content .= '<h5>SHARE ON</h5> <a class="crunchify-link crunchify-twitter" href="'. $twitterURL .'" target="_blank">Twitter</a>';
        $content .= '<a class="crunchify-link crunchify-facebook" href="'.$facebookURL.'" target="_blank">Facebook</a>';
        $content .= '<a class="crunchify-link crunchify-googleplus" href="'.$googleURL.'" target="_blank">Google+</a>';
        $content .= '<a class="crunchify-link crunchify-buffer" href="'.$bufferURL.'" target="_blank">Buffer</a>';
        $content .= '<a class="crunchify-link crunchify-pinterest" href="'.$pinterestURL.'" target="_blank">Pin It</a>';
        $content .= '</div>';

        return $content;
    }else{
        // if not a post/page then don't include sharing button
        return $content;
    }
};
add_filter( 'the_content', 'crunchify_social_sharing_buttons');

add_filter( 'social_bar', 'crunchify_social_sharing_buttons');
```

social-bar.php

```
<!-- socialbar-->
<?php
    echo apply_filters( 'social_bar');
?>
<!-- /socialbar-->
```

Display the social bar where I want

```
<?php

get_template_part('socialbar');

?>
```